# ArrayAdapter - how do I stop getView calls?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, indexoutofboundsexception

How do I stop getView calls, until I call notifyDatasetChanged() again?

My issue:

I have a textfield that filters the adapter on textchange. If I change text too frequently I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because getView is of course still accessing the list of the adapter while the seconding filtering operation is already running.

So ATM it goes like this:

1. Filter in background + notifyDatasetChanged
2. GetView called multiple times
3. While the next filter is being processed, GetView is still being called in the background because of the first filter. But GetView gets exception because of list access (filtering operation changes list). So I want to stop GetView calls and THEN start any given filter operation.

EDIT:

i was thinking of returning from getview immediately if I see the filter thread is active?

EDIT:

OK relevant adapter code:

```
@Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
      filterLock.acquireUninterruptibly();

      FilterResults r = new FilterResults();
      List<T> items = null;
      m_Filter = constraint;

      if (constraint == null /* TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint) */) { // AR
        // auskommentiert
        // da
        // ungewünscht
        items = m_AllItems;
      } else {
        items = m_FilteredItems;
        items.clear();

        synchronized (SyncLock) {
          for (T item : m_AllItems) {
            if (DynamicArrayAdapter.this.filter(item, constraint)) {
              items.add(item);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      r.values = items;
      r.count = items.size();

      return r;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

      m_Items = (List<T>) results.values;

      notifyDataSetChanged();

      filterLock.release();
    }
```

This is the filter that extends from Filter. m_Items and m_AllItems are used in the adapter (the first contains the filtered, the second the unfiltered). As you can see they on not modified in performFiltering(). Also filterLock is a size 1 semaphore so no 2 filtering operations are taking place in the same time.

EDIT2:

also, in my onTextChanged I can assure you that I do not modify the adapter there in any way either, neither do I in the filter() method that is called from performFiltering()

Comment: You shouldn't try to stop `getView()` calls, instead you should strive to implement a better filtering system. Post the code you have for the filtering operation.

Comment: You've complicated the filtering operation. The lock is mostly useless as you can't have two filtering operation running at the same time using the `Filter` class. The only synchronization needs to be done on accessing the data list. Also, make **copies** of the list don't share the lists of data.

Comment: I could swear I tracks 2 threads through performFiltering that were there together. That is why I did it. Any way does not hurt I guess

Answer (score 0):

Making changed to Adapters not from the UI thread is what causing your problems.
If you will post all your adapters modification to the UI thread it won't happen because it all happening one after the other.

You can do the heavy processing in a different thread but when you want to put the changes in the adapter you need to do it on the UI thread using a Handler or [`Activity.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29). For example:

```
// Really heavy filtering process

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
               // Change items of Adapter here
               // Now we are notifying that the data has changed.
               mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
    });
```

After seeing your code:
As Luksprog is saying, you shouldn't change the list directly from other thread but use copy of the list.
What happens is that the ListView accepts a list with size of X but you already changed it to size of Y and the ListView didn't know about it.
You need to do the work on a copy of your items list, and after you are done, post to the UI thread a `Runnable` that change the items list in the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, this was you won't have conflicts with you ListView and you Adapter.

Comment: I am not changing m_Items or M_AllItems in a thread. m_FilteredItems seen in my post is a new list already.